# Why do I need a value for self here?

Tags: python, class, self

Hey there I'm new to python and try to program a simple login module which salts a password

When I use this class I get the following error:

> TypeError: salting() missing 1 required positional argument: 'password'

```
class Login():
    def salting(self, username, password):
        self.password = password
        self.username = username

        print(self.username + self.password)

Login.salting("user1","pw1")
```

My Only Solutions were to use Login.salting("","user1","pw1") with an empty string for self or calling self as username end reuse it like this, but I think that I ran in an error, can someone help me :D

But when I compare that with my previous code which was like this (I learned that with this code) - the error doesn't appear...

```
class car():
    name = "BMW"
    color = "red"
    def redesign(self, color):
        self.color = color
c = car()
print(c.name)
print(c.color)
c.redesign("blue")
print(c.color)
```

THANKS

Comment: You have to instantiate the class first: `user = Login()` and after that use  `user.salting(username, password)`

Answer (score 2):

`salting` is an object method, not a class method. Each object has its own `username` and `password` attributes. You need to create a `Login` object, and then call the method on that.

```
s = Login()
s.salting("user1", "pw2")
```

This is analogous to using `c = car()` in the second block of code.

Comment: The class and function definitions don't change, just replace the last line with these two lines.

Comment: @MrLufus, Barmar means that you must instantiate your `Login` class (creating an object of `Login` type) and then call `salting()` on the object, not the class.

Comment: When you're doing object-oriented programming, you generally create objects.

Comment: `Login()` returns an object, and you call the method on that object, just like `s.salting()` does.

Comment: This is just basic programming. `func1().func2()` is the same as `var = func1()` followed by `var.func2()`.

Comment: You need to use parentheses to call the function.

Comment: Thanks I got it :)